# One propeller Drone?How well it works?Hope

Tags: quadcopter

Can a one propeller drone work efficiently for a good flight and stable camera footage in a drone flight

Comment: Have you seen any drone that flies with solely one propeller? The reason behind this is the stability issue. You can't stabilize this configuration of drones. Always remember instability with  unmanned aerial vehicles means crash. On one is willing to build such a complicated system and then let it crashes.

Comment: How about two propellers? I saw a video with two propellers.Helicopters fly with one propeller.I have seen a video with one propeller and it was good at functioning

Comment: The video is on youtube

Comment: Helicopters have  tails.

Comment: Another reason is the maneuverability. You can't rotate a drone with only one propeller.

Comment: A drone with a propeller and another propeller for movement below it ,unlike the quadcopter format.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it's not clear what you're asking for. Can you post a link to a "one propeller drone"?

Comment: He probably means this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6sY3L-dow8c

But I can't be 100% sure.

Comment: Yes you can, there are designs with a single propellor and 4 independent flaps: http://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/singlecopter-and-coaxcopter.html

Answer (score 2):

Helicopters are a quasi-single propeller drone, but they require a tail propeller to counter-act the effects of the lift propeller.  Due to newton's third law of motion, the lifting propeller's spin in one direction will cause the the body of the helicopter to spin in the other direction.  Without a tail propeller to overcome this effect, A single motor drone would simply spin out of control.

Comment: Nonsense, there are lots of 1-motor, 1- propeller drones that fly perfectly well.  Eg see [Ultimate 45CC-50CC Giant Scale Radio Remote Controlled RC Bi-Plane](http://www.nitroplanes.com/ul45giscrare.html)

Comment: @jwpat7, we refer to Rotary Wing Aircraft since the OP mentions in his comment the helicopters.

Comment: @CroCo, the CQ-10 Bravo (Canadian Gyroplane Cargo Carrier Unmanned Aircraft) appears to be a 1-motor, 1- propeller drone when in forward flight.  The top prop (the autogyro rotary wing) is powered for vertical take off.  See [photo and notes](http://www.regalpony.ca/chatter09A.html), about 1/4 of the way down the page

Comment: @jwpat7, but it has two propellers. As I said, another problem with one propeller is the maneuverability. Under very restricted conditions, you could build a drone with one propeller but it flies vertically and with few centimeters if not millimeters until it crashes. This is not an efficient drone, not even sufficient.

Comment: @CroCo, when an autogyro is flying horizontally it has one propellor (which rotates in the vertical plane) and one free-rotating wing (rotating in a more-or-less horizontal plane), which is not a second propellor.

Comment: I recently saw a one propeller drone a company makes.It's ina  bottle shape. And it works quite well.

Comment: @sohaib, do you have a link for that design? at least a picture or something?

Comment: Type bottle drone on Google you shall find it

Comment: @sohaibshaik: a cursory google search reveals no such single motor drone.  You claim that it exists... Prove it by posting a link.